# Navbar auto responsive in mobile version

Tags: css, laravel-8, bootstrap-5

I'm currently a beginner with web programming, I have a problem when the mobile screen changed then the navbar will go bottom, I don't see any good source codes of this problem since some of the people use hamburger style.

This is the current view of the mobile when im not changing it to smaller view

[image: Navbar Current screen mobile]

This is the view after changing the view to smaller size

[image: After changing view]

Here is the code:

```css
.servicebtn,
.contactbtn,
.careerbtn,
.aboutbtn {
  height: 40px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "bebas";
  src: url('font-family/bebas/BEBAS.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "cairo";
  src: url('font-family/cairo/Cairoreg.ttf') format('truetype');
}

.servicebtn,
.contactbtn,
.careerbtn,
.aboutbtn {
  font-family: cairo;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.nav-item {
  background-color: black !important;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.nav-item:hover,
.nav-item:focus {
  background-color: #01FF9D !important;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.boder {
  background-color: grey !important;
  color: black;
}

.active:focus {
  background-color: #01FF9D !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.nav-link {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.nav-link:focus,
.nav-link:hover {
  color: white;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link,
.nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
  color: black;
  background-color: #01FF9D !important;
  border-color: transparent !important;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs header">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text aboutbtn" aria-current="page" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#about"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i> About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text servicebtn" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#service"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Viewrify</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text contactbtn" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text careerbtn" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#career"><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i> Careers</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Well in @media I removed it cause it's not working :/ and i don't have any idea how to do it, If i changed the width of the `nav-items` then it's still the same in the image

Comment: It would help you more if you could post a minimum reproducible code here. [How to Ask a Question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can easily be done with `flexbox`. Kindly try this

```
ul.nav.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I added it on my css, the `@media screen` still the same like in the image 2 after changing the view screen.

Comment: @新Acesyyy I have updated my answer please try it again.

Comment: Should I add it on `@media screen` too?

Comment: It works! Can I use it too in the text?

Comment: _" Can I use it too in the text?"_ No text is a bit different

Comment: Okay okay. Thanks!

Comment: Use `white-space: nowrap;` for text.